# How to use recyclerview and cardview in ecilipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-cardview

I have tried copying jar files to libs folder, importing recyclerview.jar as dependencies but nothing seems to work.
Please give a solution for eclipse not Android Studio.
Any advice will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Try using android studio and gradle support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please **consider to switch to Android Studio**.

You can find all the release of the support libraries library in this folder:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/
```

Here you can check all version.
In the folders you will find the `aar` file of the support libraries.
Inside you can check the `classes.jar` file,the res folder and the AndroidManifest file.

- Create a project in your workspace
- Unzip the AAR into some directory.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `res`, and `assets` folders from the AAR into your project.
- Create a `libs` directory in your project and copy into it the `classes.jar`
- Add the dependency.
- Use the SDK 23 to compile
- Mark the project as a library

The Recyclerview library has the support-v4.jar and the support-annotations-23.x.X.jar as dependencies.